# Is there a security provision in Rails 5.1.7 that would block me from reaching localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx

After being forced to upgrade to Mac OS Sierra from Lion, I'm trying to upgrade from Rails `2.3.18` (ruby `1.8.7`) to Rails `5.1.7`. The app did run just fine on Lion with Apache `2.2.15` fronting Mongrel Cluster with MySQL `5.6.15`. The front-end is written in AS3 Flash (it's a big app).

In upgrading to Mac OS Sierra, Apple installed Apache `2.4.28`. I then used rvm and brew to get Rails `5.1.7` (ruby `2.4.1`) and the MySQL 2 gem along with passenger and edited the Apache conf file accordingly. Apache complained that my app was insecure (it's housed under `/Library/WebServer`) and that ruby (brew has it under my User directory) was insecure and would not start. The error message indicated that I should change the permissions on all involved directories to root. Tried that and Apache would start but gave me only an error page saying I was not authorized by localhost. Apple also overwrote my prior openSSL 1.1 with openssl.0.9.8. I had brew install 1.1.1d and generated new self-signed certificate.

I have since loaded mod-passenger in Apache with the same results.

I then found a blog at the Phusion Passenger site and followed their set up for using Passenger Stand Alone with SSL (I created another set of pems following their instructions and loaded these into the key chain). Attempting to start passenger I got this...

```
$ sudo passenger start --ssl --daemonize --environment development --ssl-certificate ~/certs/newcert.pem --ssl-certificate-key ~/certs/newkey.pem --port 443
Password:

*** ERROR: the Nginx configuration that Phusion Passenger Standalone generated internally contains problems. The error message returned by the Nginx engine is:

    nginx: the configuration file nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (13: Permission denied)
    nginx: configuration file nginx.conf test failed
```

This probably means that you have found a bug in Phusion Passenger Standalone. Please report this bug to our Github issue tracker: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues

Again, you'll note the Permission denied thing.

I sent the info off to Passenger last week but I doubt it's their bug.

I'm feeling I'm dealing with Apple's set-up and nothing in their Support, at least that I could find, is helpful.

**But I'm just wondering if Rails has a security something I'm not considering. That's my question.**

Sorry to have been so verbose, but please remember that I wrote this thing over 10 years ago when rails was really just starting out, so I'm a newbie again.

Comment: "_I'm just wondering if Rails has a security something I'm not considering._" No.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running anything else already on port 443 are you?

`sudo lsof -i tcp:443 -stcp:listen`

You would normally get a different error, but it pays to check anyway.

Lion is pretty old, but it did have the application firewall in place.  Are you sure your machine's firewall is set up correctly?  Normally, when you run something that listens to a port, you will see this popup:

[image: PopupAcceptIncomingConnections]

However, if you have clicked the "Deny" button, it stays denied.  So, go to System Preferences > Security and Privacy.  Click the lock at the bottom left to unlock the settings, then click "Firewall Options".  You should see this:
[image]

Let Ruby accept incoming connections, as well as nginx, etc.  You will need to do this for those applications that are not signed nor built-in, which is pretty much everything useful from a brew install.

Click "OK" and then try again.  If the popup appears, select "Allow", else shampoo, rinse, and repeat this answer.

Of course, you can just turn off your firewall.  Don't do that.  Seriously.

I'm not sure this is your problem, but since it is affecting several different command line applications, it seems a good place to start.

Check [This doc from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642) for pretty much the same info.